# RedBeanPHP добавить переменную в SQL запрос

Tags: sql, redbeanphp

У меня есть запрос:

```
$location = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE location = :location',
    [':location' => $_POST["search-location"]]
);
```

Нужно подставить переменную здесь: ... 'SELECT * FROM $variable_name ...

Comment: Имя таблицы не параметризуется. Либо прямая подстановка в текст на стороне PHP, либо динамический SQL на стороне Sql-сервера. См. https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying, начиная со слов "For dynamic queries use R::getWriter()->esc() & R::getPDO()->quote()".

Comment: @Akina Большое вам спасибо!